# Extra and misaligned rows when importing data in SAS

Tags: import, sas

I am trying to import data in SAS like:

```
A   B    C    D    E
x   y    z    h    i
s1  s2   s3   s4   s5
```

where A B C D and E are column names.

I have 240 columns in my dataset and the code I am using is:

```
data INFO;
infile Attdata notab dlm='09'x dsd missover LRECL = 100000000;
length A B C D E $200; (I am importing 240 columns)
input A B C D E;
run;
```

Whenever I import data, some of the rows of column B, C etc, gets stacked below rows of A:

```
A   B    C    D    E
x             h    i
s1  s2  s3        s5
y   s4
z
```

Is there a way to fix this? Do I need to do something with lrecl one? My data gets all weird after running this code. Might there be problem with length one?

Comment: I suggest working on the [formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in this question. It's a little unreadable, and I'm not quite sure how to make it right.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. I have tried to make my question redable enough. I have been struggling really hard to fix this and not sure what i should change for formatting. I have some columns with only text data and some have percentages. Would you suggest something for formatting? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your edit helped, Nupur, and I did a little more.

Comment: Thanks Michael! This looks perfect now.

Answer (score 0):

It may be something to do with missover (rather than LRECL). I have found this site to be useful in the past: http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi26/p009-26.pdf

Are you saying in your question that data from line 1 is appearing on lines 3 and 4 and some data from line 2 is on line 3? I've never seen SAS do this before.

You may want to check your delimiter/end of line characters.